# How do you save the state of a widget in a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter, ipywidgets

I have a radio button widget in a Jupyter notebook and I want to save the selected state, preferrably in the notebook json. That doesn't seem to be happening when I save the notebook. The state gets lost and reset when you reopen the notebook. Is there a way to save the state and have it reload?

Answer (score 1):

To save a widget state in a jupyter notebook use `Save Notebook Widget State` menu item (Widgets>Save Notebook Widget State).  From [ipywidgets](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/embedding.html#save-notebook-widget-state):

> A notebook file may be saved with the current widget state as
>   metadata. This allows the notebook file to be rendered with rendered
>   widgets

[image]